# How do I sort the results of a LINQ to SQL query using approximation?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I wrote the following extension method for LINQ to OBJECTS which performs exactly what I want but I can not get it to work with LINQ to SQL.

```
 <Extension()> Public Function ThenByLike(Of T As Class)(ByVal items As IOrderedEnumerable(Of T), PropertySelector As Func(Of T, String), Ascending As Boolean, ParamArray Searches As String()) As IOrderedEnumerable(Of T)
        Searches = If(Searches, {})
        If Searches.Count > 0 Then
            For Each t In Searches
                For Each exp In {
                    Function(x) PropertySelector(x) = t,
                    Function(x) PropertySelector(x).StartsWith(t),
                    Function(x) PropertySelector(x).Contains(t),
                    Function(x) PropertySelector(x).EndsWith(t)
                  }

                    If Ascending Then
                        items = items.ThenByDescending(exp)
                    Else
                        items = items.ThenBy(exp)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If


        Return items
    End Function
```

I get the following exception:

> Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported
>   translation to SQL.

What do I need to do to make the method compatible with LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Answers in C # are valid for me.

Comment: Is the intention of those four functions the same as `Function(x) PropertySelector(x).IndexOf(t) >= 0`?

Comment: Or perhaps ordering by `PropertySelector(x).IndexOf(t) / t.Length` would be sufficient? With some consideration for when `PropertySelector(x).IndexOf(t) < 0`.

Comment: Your function just cannot be translated to a SQL query on the server. A LINQ to SQL will be executed on the SQL server, so the usable functions are limited. (since I'm to lazy to google by myself: I'm not even sure if the 'IF' or the loop is even supported.)

Comment: In order to use a user-defined function in a LINQ to SQL (or EF) query and have it expand to the proper `Expression` types to be translated to a SQL query, you must restrict your UDF to translatable methods and use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). Consider `SQLMethods.Like`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to translate the function to the following code to get a valid SQL query to run on SQL Server.

```
 <Extension()> Public Function ThenByLike(Of T)(ByVal items As IOrderedQueryable(Of T), Searches As String(), SortProperty As Expression(Of Func(Of T, String)), Optional Ascending As Boolean = True) As IOrderedQueryable(Of T)
        Dim type = GetType(T)
        Searches = If(Searches, {})
        For Each t In Searches
            Dim mem As MemberExpression = SortProperty.Body
            Dim [property] = mem.Member
            Dim parameter = SortProperty.Parameters.First
            Dim propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, [property])
            Dim orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter)

            Dim tests As MethodCallExpression() = {
                    Expression.Call(propertyAccess, startsWithMethod, Expression.Constant(t)),
                    Expression.Call(propertyAccess, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(t)),
                    Expression.Call(propertyAccess, endsWithMethod, Expression.Constant(t))
                    }

            For Each exp In tests
                Dim nv = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(exp, parameter)
                If Ascending Then
                    items = items.ThenByDescending(nv)
                Else
                    items = items.ThenBy(nv)
                End If
            Next

        Next
        Return items
    End Function

    Private containsMethod As MethodInfo = GetType(String).GetMethod("Contains")

    Private endsWithMethod As MethodInfo = GetType(String).GetMethod("EndsWith", {GetType(String)})

    Private startsWithMethod As MethodInfo = GetType(String).GetMethod("StartsWith", {GetType(String)})
```